# Download attribute on anchor-tag not working with relative path in edge

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I'm baffled, by the issue presented to me today. We use the download-Attribute for File-Downloads from the same-source. So it's no issue working in Chrome, Firefox, Safari or anything else. But I get a problem with MS Edge as it is not download the resource. It just does nothing, the dialog appears where I want to save the file or directly open it, but it doesn't download it, I can press "Save" as often as I want. MS Edge has no issue to display the file if I leave out the download attribute and absolute paths to other sources work without an issue.

```
<a class="atm-context_menu_item " download="" 
href="../../mocks/modules/topiclist/topiclist.json" data-context- 
menu="item">
    <svg class="icon atm-context_menu_item__icon">
        <use xlink:href="#download"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="visuallyhidden">Download</span>
    <span class="atm-context_menu_item__label">Sprache</span>
</a>
```

No error messages and the file is definitely there where we point it to.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Microsoft Edge version are you using? I have tried to test your code on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0), it works well.

From the [download attribute document](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp), it seems that this attribute support Microsoft Edge 13+, please check your Edge browser version and try to upgrade the Edge browser version.

Besides, you could also try [resetting the Edge browser setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10).

Comment: It's MSEdge 42.17134.1.0, I'll try to update it. But it is seen on many versions and via BrowserStack. The Download Attribute works fine with absolute paths in Edge.